# preventing submit if a variable is empty

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to prevent submit on a form IF any variable is empty.
The form have readio buttons and checkboxes. no text inputs.

I have tried to define an empty() function in diferent ways.
one way was

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function empty(){
var x
x = document.GetElementsByName("ojos").value;
if (x == ""){
alert("please answer the question");
return false;
};
}
</script>
```

---

on the form tag I added < ...... Onsubmit="empty()" />

another way was

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function empty(){
var empt = document.forms["form1"]["ojos"].value;
if (empt == "")
{
alert("Please answer the question");
return false;
}

</script>
```

a last try was like this:

```
$("form#form1").submit(function(empty) {
    empty.preventDefault();

    var ojos     = $('#ojos').val();
    var pelo    = $('#pelo').val();
    var piel     = $('#piel').val();
    var comoda     = $('#comoda').val();



    if(ojos && pelo && piel && comoda){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update-2.php",
            data: "ojos="+ ojos +"& pelo="+ pelo +"& piel="+ piel +"& comoda="+ comoda,
            success: function(){
                $('form#form1').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

            }
        });
     }
     return false; 
});
```

here I tried to use the function to check 4 values at the same time (this one is not clear to me, I just saw it on internet and gave it a try, so it may be compleatly wrong)

The result is allways the same, the form get submitted and handled by my update-2.php file. If any variable is empty it will update it to an empty value or "null" on my database.

I need to prevent the submission if there is any empty value. I'm trying to do it with one value until I get it right and then just apply it to all of the form.

my function is in the the end of my body tags, and I tried to add Onsubmit to the form tags and onclick to the submit input in order to trigger the function.
nothing seems to work.

Comment: this is not the same question, he was trying to validate the date, I'm trying to prevent submit id a variable is either empty or null. I actually have some options but nothis is working and I read the post you marked and the solution for him would not help me,,,, so how is that you marked my question as duplicate??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(ojos != "" && pelo != "" && piel != "" && comoda != ""){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update-2.php",
            data: "ojos="+ ojos +"& pelo="+ pelo +"& piel="+ piel +"& comoda="+ comoda,
            success: function(){
                $('form#form1').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

            }
        });
     }
else{
alert("Please Fill")
return false;

}
```

Try With `val != ""`

Comment: tried it, still it will just submit the form @_@

Comment: @EstebanLuques try with those